# Lower bound elevation in sub classes

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a hierarchy of classes that can be simplified to the following example

```
public interface I<T> {
  T get();
}

public interface II<T extends Number> extends I<T> {
}

public class A implements II<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer get() {
    return null;
  }
}

public class B implements II<Double> {
  @Override
  public Double get() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Now when I'm trying to compile the following code

```
    II ii = new A();
    Number n = ii.get();
```

I get a compiler error (at the 2nd line)

```
java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.Number
```

I understand that it is because the it takes the lower bound of `I` which is `Object` (since method `get` is declared in `I`) but I was expecting that it will take the lower bound of `II`. How can I refactor this hierarchy such that the compiler will consider `Number` as lower bound. The only restriction is that interface `I` cannot be modified because it is part of a library.

UPDATE: The idea is that I would like a generic solution

```
    II ii = <any instance of classes that implements interface II>
    Number n = ii.get();
```

Comment: What happens if you declare `T get();` also in the interface `II`?

Comment: compiles without errors but in the real problem, interface `I` has 10 methods and I don't want to redeclare them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You shouldn't use raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) `II`. Replace it with `II<?>`, and everything will work fine:

```
II<?> ii = new A();
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything else is ok, declaration need to be changed to `II<Integer> ii = new A();`, then it works.

For both `A` and `B`, you can use `II<? extends Number> = new A();`

Comment: I would like to have a generic solution, which will work for both `ii  = new A()` and `ii = new B()` and so on, `A` and `B` are dependencies

Comment: Edited answer to reflect this